# Bug in NSCalendar's calendar.rangeOfUnit func?

Tags: swift, nsdate, nscalendar

I made a quick playground [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlWA5.png) to exhibit what appears to be a bug in NSCalendar's rangeOfUnit func.

After some initial statements you can see my output for

```
let secs = calendar.rangeOfUnit(.Second, inUnit: .Month, forDate: firstOfMonth!).length
```

is 60. I was expecting to see 2678400 (60secs * 60mins * 24hrs * 31days). Am I doing something wrong?

Also I thought I'd stress the func with a nearly trivial

```
let months = calendar.rangeOfUnit(.Month, inUnit: .Month, forDate: firstOfMonth!).length
```

and was bewildered with the result value of 9223372036854775807. Anyone have an explanation for that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `ordinalityOfUnit()` method

First we need the end of the month date.

```
var firstOfMonth:NSDate? = nil
var seconds: NSTimeInterval = 0
calendar().rangeOfUnit(.Month, startDate: &firstOfMonth, interval: &seconds, forDate: NSDate())
let endOfMonth = firstOfMonth?.dateByAddingTimeInterval(seconds-1)
```

than we can do

```
let secs = calendar().ordinalityOfUnit(.Second, inUnit: .Month, forDate: endOfMonth!)
```

`secs` now holds `2678400`

```
let min = calendar().ordinalityOfUnit(.Minute, inUnit: .Month, forDate: endOfMonth!)
let hour= calendar().ordinalityOfUnit(.Hour, inUnit: .Month, forDate: endOfMonth!)
```

---

`9223372036854775807`<sub>10</sub> == `111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111`<sub>2</sub>
This number is the highest Int value in 64bit.
also `NSNotFound = NSIntegerMax`

`func rangeOfUnit(_: inUnit:forDate:) -> NSRange` docs states

> […] Returns {NSNotFound, NSNotFound} if larger is not logically bigger than smaller in the calendar, or the given combination of units does not make sense […]

Comment: Thanks @vikingosegundo. Works! :)